# How can I prohibit the capture of the mouse and keyboard?

Tags: fedora, kde, keyboard, mouse

I use Fedora 38 with KDE 5.27.9.

I have an application, which is just a kind of remote desktop tool, which I need running all the time. And like all this type of applications, it has mouse and keyboard capture.
You can press the hotkey and it will release your devices, but the problem is that
then the program will exit after some time and you don't have any option to prevent this behaviour. So until you don't press the hotkey, you good to go, I'm sure it works just like this, because I've tested it several times.

So, right now I'm unsuccessfully looking for the solution, which will help me blocking mouse and keyboard capture for the specific app.

I've tried using workspaces and it kinda work, it releases my mouse and keyboard, but app still listens to mouse and keyboard and everything keeps sending to the machine.

Unfortunately, I can't use any another application. I hope you can help me with that, thanks!

Comment: maybe try `usbguard` and create its `.conf` file having no allowed devices, then when `service usbguard start` is done there will be no usb kybd or mouse recognized, but you will however be able to ssh in and have functionality; doing a `service usbguard stop` would then reactive the connected usb kybd & mouse and give a functional console.